# React Native Bottom Tab Navigation: Hide tab from navigator if on the current screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am still trying to learn react native. I have 4 screens but only want to use 3 buttons on my tab navigator. I would like to remove or hide the tab of the active screen. So for example, if I am on the home screen I do not want the home tab button available to press on the navigator and only the remaining 3 tabs would be available to press.

I have tried using state to track which screen I am on and conditionally display the tab button with:
`tabBarButton: isHomeScreen ? undefined : (props) => null,`

Which I was almost sure would work but then I got the following error:
`TypeError: false is not a function`

Here are some snippets with what I have done:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  const [isHomeScreen, setIsHomeScreen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      backBehavior="history"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: { height: 75 },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        children={() => <HomeScreen setIsHomeScreen={setIsHomeScreen} />}
        options={{
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Home",
          tabBarButton: isHomeScreen && ((props) => null),
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
              }}
              source={require("../../assets/icons/tab_navigator/home.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        children={() => <ProfileScreen setIsHomeScreen={setIsHomeScreen} />}
        options={{
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Profile",
          tabBarButton: isHomeScreen ? undefined : (props) => null,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Avatar source={dummyData.profileSource} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="CreatePoll"
        children={() => <CreatePollScreen setIsHomeScreen={setIsHomeScreen} />}
        options={{
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Create Poll",
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Image
              style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
              source={require("../../assets/icons/tab_navigator/create-poll.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        children={() => (
          <NotificationsScreen setIsHomeScreen={setIsHomeScreen} />
        )}
        options={{
          tabBarAccessibilityLabel: "Notifications",
          tabBarBadge: 4, // To Fix: Make dynamic
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Image
              style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
              source={require("../../assets/icons/tab_navigator/notification.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

In all the screens I have something along the lines of:

```
const ProfileScreen = ({ setIsHomeScreen }) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  if (isFocused) {
    setIsHomeScreen(false);
  }

  return <Text>PROFILE SCREEN</Text>;
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this complete solution below, You can achieve what you want using createBottomTabNavigator from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" configuration.

**Step 1:** Configure Tab.Navigator Screen Options, and you can pass the Tab Name which you don't want to display. For example in the below code "Home" Tab wont be displayed.

```
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarButton: ["Home"].includes(route.name)
        ? () => {
            return null;
          }
        : undefined,
      headerShown: false,
    })}
  >
```

**Step 2:** Make the tabBarButton parameter configurable like you can pass a dynamic parameter. The below code has screenName as the dynamic parameter

```
const [screenName, setScreenName] = useState("");

      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarButton: [screenName].includes(route.name)
            ? () => {
                return null;
              }
            : undefined,
          headerShown: false,
        })}
      >
```

**Step 3:** Create javascript function to update the dynamic parameter

```
  const setCurrentScreen = (screenValue) => {
    updateData(screenValue);
    console.log("setCurrentScreen is Called: " + screenValue);
  };

  const updateData = async (screenValue) => {
    await setScreenName(screenValue);
  };
```

**Step 4:** Set the tab name to the dynamic parameter on Tab Clik. You can capture the tab click event using the listeners attribute on Tab.Screen

```
<Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log("Home Tab Clicked");
              setCurrentScreen("Home");
              // Prevent default action if needed
              //e.preventDefault();
            },
          }}
        />
```

Complete React Native JS App.js code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useState } from "react";

const ProfileScreen = () => {
  console.log("Profile Screen");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>PROFILE SCREEN</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
  console.log("Home Screen");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>HOME SCREEN</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const CreatePollScreen = () => {
  console.log("CreatePoll Screen");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>CREATE POLL SCREEN</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const NotificationsScreen = () => {
  console.log("Notifications Screen");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>NOTIFICATIONS SCREEN</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [screenName, setScreenName] = useState("");

  const setCurrentScreen = (screenValue) => {
    updateData(screenValue);
    console.log("setCurrentScreen is Called: " + screenValue);
  };

  const updateData = async (screenValue) => {
    await setScreenName(screenValue);
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarButton: [screenName].includes(route.name)
            ? () => {
                return null;
              }
            : undefined,
          headerShown: false,
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log("Home Tab Clicked");
              setCurrentScreen("Home");
              // Prevent default action if needed
              //e.preventDefault();
            },
          }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log("Profile Tab Clicked");
              setCurrentScreen("Profile");
              // Prevent default action if needed
              //e.preventDefault();
            },
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="CreatePoll"
          component={CreatePollScreen}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log("CreatePoll Tab Clicked");
              setCurrentScreen("CreatePoll");
              // Prevent default action if needed
              //e.preventDefault();
            },
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Notifications"
          component={NotificationsScreen}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              console.log("Notifications Tab Clicked");
              setCurrentScreen("Notifications");
              // Prevent default action if needed
              //e.preventDefault();
            },
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

My Package JSON file

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

In Profile Screen You can see only Home, Create Poll and Notifications

[image]

In Home Screen you can see only Profile, Create Poll and Notifcations [image]